# Laravel Configuration update

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am working on Laravel. I have questions about update / add configuration dynamically. Let me tell you my question.

I am updating / add the global configuration of my project using the file_put_content in config file. I have another way, save configuration into the database and pull that configuration at the time of login to the system.

Which way is better to use and why?

Comment: Don't store conf settings inside conf file.... there should only be the "default settings" and all custom settings should be inside .env file. Then you can save .env file into DB

Answer (score 3):

one way is maintain seprate table for config data if your data is static means nothing have to change in that data. and then create `provider` to get your data and bind that data at run time

```
public function boot()
    {
        if (Schema::hasTable('roles')) {
            $roles = Role::pluck('name', 'id')->all();
            $data = collect($roles)->mapWithKeys(function ($item, $index) {
                return [str_slug($item, '_') => $index];
            })->all();
            config(['configfilename.configkey' => $data]);
        }
    }
```

Like this you can get your config data at run time